# Mysql: how to design a database to display one article in different menus

Tags: stored-procedures, database-design, relational-database, mysql-workbench, database-schema

I want to append one article to different menus. Please take a look at a procedure for adding a new article. My implementation works fine, but seems to be far from perfect.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS new_article;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE new_article(IN title VARCHAR(255), IN alias VARCHAR(255), IN text MEDIUMTEXT, IN description TEXT, IN articles_users_id INT, IN menus_id INT)
BEGIN
    /*how do i know a first VALUE for articles_menus INSERT?*/
    SET @articles_id_ai =  (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT
    FROM information_schema.tables
    WHERE table_name = 'articles'
    AND table_schema = DATABASE());
    INSERT INTO articles VALUE (@articles_id_ai, articles_users_id, title, alias, text, description, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
    INSERT INTO articles_menus VALUE (@articles_id_ai, articles_users_id, menus_id);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the way you are getting the next auto generated value for the table. So I don't know what would happen if a different user wrote to the table after your first SELECT but before your first INSERT. MySQL provides an easy way to retrieve the last generated value, LAST_INSERT_ID():

```
INSERT INTO articles( users_id, title, alias, text, desc )
    VALUES( articles_users_id, title, alias, text, description );
INSERT INTO articles_menus( articles_id, articles_users_id, menus_id )
    VALUES( LAST_INSERT_ID(), articles_users_id, menus_id );
```

This uses only two database accesses instead of three and it uses the function provided for the purpose. It's generally a good idea to use the system-provided methods to get information unless you have a good reason. Nobody knows the system better than the developers of system functions.